# How to Drop down the DateTimePicker Programmatically? - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Wondering how I could drop down the calendar of DateTimePicker

So I have the below code/event when a TextBox clicked, instantiate a new a DataTimePicker programmatically and added to the Form.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click

        Dim dtm = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker()
        With dtm
            .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Comic Sans MS", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
            .Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(153, 237)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(173, 35)
        End With

        Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(dtm)
        dtm.Show()

    End Sub
```

The above shows the DateTimePicker.

How could I display the "Drop Down" calendar as soon as the DateTimePicker is shown

Comment: You have asked two separate questions, which is not allowed, regardless of whether it seems convenient. please edit your post to ask a single question and then post the second question separately.

Comment: Also, what you're doing seems bizarre. Why not just use a `DateTimePicker` instead of the `TextBox` in the first place? If you must use a `TextBox`, what happens if someone uses the keyboard to focus it? Also, why not use a `MonthCalendar` instead of a `DateTimePicker` if you only want the calendar and not the text field?

Comment: @Jhon perfect! I am a newbie to vb.net forms. So I did not know about the MonthCalender component. Thanks. You may want to answer the question by using MonthCalendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calendar part is the only reason for the `DateTimePicker` then a `MonthCalendar` control would be more appropriate. There's no dropping down in that case, so you can just show the control when and where you want.